# Django test organization questions

Tags: django

In the interest of decoupled code, I've created several apps in my project that can exist without the others being there.  Any app can be removed from the project without breaking things later down the line.

To do this, I've created some tests that make use of the `@override_settings` decorator in Django 1.4, however, I would like to test the functionality of the apps and their interaction together.

So, I would like to have tests that do not make the apps depend on each other, but I would also like to have tests that test the project as a whole.  Where is the normal place to store these?  Are there any tricks to doing this?

Comment: +1 for @override_settings, I love it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any established convention, but what I usually do is that I create an app called, for example, `tests` and place the higher-level, integration tests there.